# Relationship between Cell and Range() in VBA with ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel

I learning VBA and am really confused as to what exactly `Range()` takes in for VBA. I have a pretty solid grasp of OOP and languages like Java / Python, but VBA is throwing me a bit for a loop here.

I get an error when I try to use

```
Set MyRange = Range(ActiveCell, Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown)))
```

I know that the correct solution is

```
Set MyRange = Range(ActiveCell,ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
```

But I'm trying to understand why this is the case. The error is specifically coming from `Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown))`. I know that `.End()` returns a `Range` object from [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel).

However, when I write

```
MsgBox (TypeName(ActiveCell))
```

I am informed that `ActiveCell` is a `Range` object. `Range("A1")` works perfectly fine (of course), while `Range(ActiveCell)` throws an error, so I guess this confirms that `Range()` doesn't take in `Range` objects.

However, `"A1"` is clearly a `String`. When I type in `Range()` into my VBA editor, I see that `Range()` accepts `Cell` as argument parameters. So what is the relationship between a `Cell` and a `Range` in the world of `VBA`? Does a `Range` inherit from a `Cell`? I'm confused as to why `Range()` accepts other `Range` objects, and also `String`?

And if `Range()` doesn't accept `Range` objects as parameters, then why does this following piece of code work?

`Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`

Isn't `.End()` returning a `Range` object here?

Comment: This would be a good read for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Range is looking for a string that represents a cell address or two range objects that note the extent of the range.

ActiveCell is a range object in itself.  So when using it inside Range:

> `Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown))`

The range is looking for the second range object.

You can return the address as a string:

> `Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Address)`

Which will work but will force vbe to do a lot of conversions.  It is like converting DC power to AC back to DC to charge your phone.

Simply using:

> `ActiveCell.End(xlDown)`

as the range object works.

```
Set MyRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
```

This is the reason `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))` works.  you are returning two range objects.  vbe assumes the `"A2"` in the first place of the range to be `Range("A2")`

> `Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`

Works as each of the interior ranges are using the string to create the range object.

Your first is like:

> `Range("A2", Range(Range("A2")).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`

As you can see the second Range is now trying to find a range with only one range object and it would need two to be a viable range.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation. So `Range()` can take in a mixture of both `String` and `Range` objects? Like in the example of `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`, its first parameter argument is a String, and the second parameter argument is a Range object?

Answer (score 1):

As `ActiveCell.End(xlDown)` already returns a range, you don't need to wrap it into Range()

Try with

```
Set MyRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
```

Comment: Thanks- I've added an edit. I knew this going in- sorry for not being more clear. But I'm trying to understand why. Because in `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`, the `Range()` is taking in a `Range` object.

Comment: Scott Craner 's answer is the most complete  !